# how to run .jsx photoshop scripts on image in java?

Tags: javascript, java, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

I am writing a java program to make an edit to a sequence of images, but I am looking for an easy and flexible way to do this edit using the Image Editors Scripts (eg: Photoshop Scripts, Gimp Scripts, ...).

Can I run Photoshop Scripts or GIMP Scripts on images in a Java Program ?

I know that these scripts are written in Javascript. At least, can I run a javascript functions in a JVM ? and is there some Photoshop APIs (jars) that I should add to make editing images with scripts works properly ?

**UPDATE**

It's clear that running JavaScript codes using the Nashorn from answers, but I still need some answers.

I am looking if it is possible to run the photoshop or GIMP scripts on nashorn like a normal script and get the result in the java program ?

It does not need any dependencies or some libraries to make running the script on images work properly ?

How to put an image as parameter before running the script and get the result after running it to do other things on the new image like printing it or saving it or even running another script ?

Thank you

Comment: A Photoshop script needs Photoshop - Photoshop is a dependency of the script. All the script does is instruct Photoshop to do specific things.

I'm assuming GIMP would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) is what you're looking for.

> It can run scripts as JavaFX applications

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy way to run existing photoshop or gimp scripts outside of photoshop/gimp. Since gimp is open source, with potentially a lot of work it may be possible to get it working. With photoshop all you have is documentation.

So probably the only way would be to allow your own script, for example in javascript. And as other answer already says, you can run javascripts from java using [nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html). In general, I think such question is too broad to be fully answered on stackoverflow as I don't think it's something that has a quick and easy solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think nashorn is very useful for running javascript codes but it still to know from the graphic designers if the photoshop/gimp scripts are only javascript code to apply the edit to images or these scripts uses some libs of photoshop or gimp tools.